# Show static files on nginx on port 80 and reverse proxy on a different port

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Before writing this, I read up on a lot of reverse-proxy nginx threads...

I'm showing static files on location / and other subdirectories which works and I want location /upload to hit a separate app running on port 8000 which does not work.

```
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.12.2
```

I'm running a simple web server on port 8000 under my home user. It contains an `upload` directory which contains a tiny file.

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

My config

```
server {
    // start default settings
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    // end default settings

    // show directory contents minus size if index not found
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;

    location / {
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /upload {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

I checked the /var/log/nginx/error.log and it seems to get the route and acknowledge that the correct upstream is selected, then returns permission denied.

> 2018/04/19 22:56:43 [error] 8960#0: *547 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server: _, request: "GET /upload/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/", host: "example.domain.com"

I can hit `127.0.0.1:8000` and `127.0.0.1:8000/upload` locally from the server but cannot hit `nginxserver/upload` from outside the server and have it reverse proxy to the python script.

Comment: nginx is not installed correctly, because you have deleted some of its files. Reinstall it. Do not move or delete any of the files it installs, nor use its directories for your own files.

Comment: Weird because I haven't removed any of its files. It was a basic yum install on centos 7 but I will try to reinstall. Thank you.